# help at solving a system

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Given a function $f(x)=x+\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}-2$, I have to solve the following system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}=y+2\\ 
y+\sqrt[3]{y}+\sqrt[5]{y}=z+2\\
z+\sqrt[3]{z}+\sqrt[5]{z}=x+2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Could you give me any hint? Thank you very much!

Comment: what about $x=y=z=1$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Using the function $f$ the system can be written as:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x)=y\\ 
f(y)=z\\
f(z)=x
\end{matrix}\right.$$
In particular:
$$f(f(f(x)))=x$$
Now you can notice that:
$$f(x) > x \text{ if } x>1$$
$$f(x) < x \text{ if } x<1$$
$$f(1)=1$$

Then you can prove that:

- if $x>1$ then $f(f(f(x)))>x$
- if $x<1$ then $f(f(f(x)))<x$

to conclude that the only solution is $x=y=z=1$.